# Android and his slow webview. Hardware accelerated is buggy

Tags: android, performance, webview, gpu

Can someone post his experience with android webview and performance?
My min API is >= android 4.0

What we can do for increasing performance of webview for all users?

1. set: android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in AndroidManifest/Application
2. set: android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in AndroidManifest/Application
3. setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); on webview
4. setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null); on webview
5. getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH); on webview

but.. here goes the main problem, some of them will speed up your webview and some of them may slow it down. It depends on device/android version.

My question is about.. is there known rules which config works on which android/device?

Also webview with hardware acceleration may lead to unexpected disappearing dom elements from your website (for me it was fixed positioned element). How to fix it?

Comment: If you can afford to increase the size of the application, then you can replace the webview with the Crosswalk Framework ( https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/embedding_crosswalk.html and https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/embedding_crosswalk/crosswalk_aar.html ), minSDK 14 and it provides a Chromium/Blink-based webview for all android devices

Comment: I've heard about it. People says that it has gpu black list and may crash on some devices. Also you have to build app separately for x86 and ARM and then do some tricky hard work on google play for each device.

Comment: Have you found out anything more about this yet? I'm looking at a very similar issue. >5.0 only, but performance is good if I downgrade WebView on the device to the stock version.

Comment: @GeirSmestad: WebView on android 5.0 should be fast as hell. So the problem is in another place. Check your config, maybe webview has turned off hardware acceleration?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The webview actually performs better with hardware acceleration turned off, which is unsettling. Testing on a Nexus 7.

Comment: We are still talking about Android 5.0?

Comment: Yes, a Nexus 7 running Android 5.0.2. Downgrading Android System Webview from 44.0.2403.117 to "Version 38 (1649326-arm)" resolves the issue, but this is just a temporary workaround. I'm trying to get to the bottom of why the unusably bad performance degradation occurs in the first place. Also using Xamarin, that's probably pertinent. Although Xamarin claims that the issue is not on their side.

Comment: Try raw webview simple project and see how your webapp works.

Comment: Figured it out. We have a subclassed WebView somewhere in our application. This overrode the OnMeasure method, probably in a way which violated the specification. It worked well until the August 6 WebView update from Google. Fixing the OnMeasure method solved the problem.